# DBArrayList to List<Map> Conversion after Query

Tags: sql, groovy

Currently, I have a SQL query that returns information to me in a DBArrayList.

It returns data in this format : `[{id=2kjhjlkerjlkdsf324523}]`

For the next step, I need it to be in a `List<Map>` format without the id: `[2kjhjlkerjlkdsf324523]`

The Datatypes being used are DBArrayList, and List.

If it helps any, the next step is a function to collect the list and then to replace all single quotes if any [SQL-Injection prevention]. Using:

```
listMap = listMap.collect() { "'" + Util.removeSingleQuotes(it) + "'" }


public static String removeSingleQuotes(s) {
    return s ? s.replaceAll(/'"/, '') : s
  }
```

Comment: Ask question with the error what u got. https://groovy-lang.org/databases.html

Comment: You are looking at the .toString of said data structure. Whatever "DBArrayList" is, it's most likely already a list of maps. Have you tried using it just as that?  And if it's unclear, don't debug with toString - use inspect or dump instead: it gives you way more insight about what data types are involved.

Comment: I wasn't getting an error, it just wasn't registering the collect.
Thanks @cfrick I investigated the Data Structure I was messing with a bit more like you suggested with logging and that helped a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using a DBArrayList is not wrong, Groovy's idiom is to use the db result as a collection. I would suggest you use it that way directly from the db:

```
Map myMap = [:]
dbhandle.eachRow("select fieldSomeID, fieldSomeVal from yourTable;") { row ->
    map[row.fieldSomeID] = row.fieldSomeVal.replaceAll(/'"/, '')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I spent this morning working on it, and I found out that I needed to actually collect the DBArrayList like this:

```
listMap = dbArrayList.collect { it.getAt('id')}
```

If you're in a bind like I was and restrained to a specific schema this might help, but @ou_ryperd has the correct answer!